# Not able to see the Storefront toolkit on the custom isml rendered in the storefront

Tags: demandware

I am not able to see the Storefront toolkit on the isml rendered in the storefront. It is there on the sitegenesis landing page. But when I supply my pipeline name and start node name in the URL, then the corresponding isml mentioned in the pipeline is rendered, but without the storefront toolkit. Do we have to do some extra configuration?

Comment: Typically there is not any configuration required. Can you post your template code?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your custom template uses a content-type other than text/html. If I recall correctly only templates that set their content type to text/html will receive the storefront toolkit. (text/html is the default)

Comment: It didn't help. Earlier, I had explicitly mentioned the content type to text/html and now I removed the <iscontent> tag and the toolkit is still not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem somewhat similar. I wasn't able to see the Storefront Toolkit too. I've solved my problem with clearing my cookies.

> developer tools > application > cookies > clear

Hope this helps to others experiencing the same problem.

Comment: This question itself looks alien to me now :D No longer working with demandware.
But thanks for the answer. Might help others who face the same issue.